# Properties are undefined of "name" in my components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I am doing an Ecommerce project and I came with this issue, When I click the “**Add to cart**” button **twice** on the first product and navigate to Cart page it works fine *(2 quantity of same product added)* but after I add something to cart and when I did the same thing it throws me the error after I pressed the Cart Icon:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name') at components\Cart.tsx (73:32)
```

Then I found out that sometimes the `onAdd()` function on `StateContext.js` updates the `cartItem` to be `undefined`.

Little explanation about my code:

- `onAdd()`: It is a function that adds the selected item to cart. It takes 2 arguments→`products,qty`. It's defined in `StateContext.js`
- `cartItems` and `setCartItems()`: These are the `useState` function variables defined in StateContext.js. It stores all the items that are being added to cart.

Here's my code which is the Add to cart snippet:

```html
<button type="button" className={styles.add_to_cart} onClick={() =>onAdd(product,qty)}>Add to Cart</button>
```

Here is my `Cart.tsx` file code (`CartItems` maps a `undefined` item in the array which is causing this error):

```js
{
  cartItems.length >= 1 &&
    cartItems?.map((item) => {
      console.log(item)
      return (
        <div
          className={styles.product}
          key={item._id}>
          <img
            src={urlFor(item?.image[0])}
            className={styles.cart_product_image}
          />
          <div className={styles.item_desc}>
            <div className={`${styles.flex} ${styles.top}`}>
              <h5>{item.name}</h5>
              <h4>₹ {item.price}</h4>
            </div>
            //some more code....
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    })
}
```

`StateContext.js` file. The `onAdd()` function code snippet Which I doubt is causing the error.

```js
import React, {
  createContext,
  useContext,
  useState,
  useEffect,
} from 'react'
import {toast} from 'react-hot-toast'

const Context = createContext()

export const StateContext = ({children}) => {
  const [showCart, setShowCart] = useState(false)
  const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState([])
  const [totalPrice, setTotalPrice] = useState(0)
  const [totalQuantities, setTotalQuantities] = useState(0)
  const [qty, setQty] = useState(1)

  const onAdd = (product, quantity) => {
    const checkProductInCart = cartItems.find(
      (item) => item._id === product._id
    )

    setTotalPrice(
      (prevTotalPrice) => prevTotalPrice + product.price * quantity
    )
    setTotalQuantities(
      (prevTotalQuantities) => prevTotalQuantities + quantity
    )

    if (checkProductInCart) {
      const updatedCartItems = cartItems.map((cartProduct) => {
        if (cartProduct._id === product._id)import React, { createContext, useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { toast } from 'react-hot-toast';

const Context = createContext();

export const StateContext = ({ children }) => {
  const [showCart, setShowCart] = useState(false);
  const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState([]);
  const [totalPrice, setTotalPrice] = useState(0);
  const [totalQuantities, setTotalQuantities] = useState(0);
  const [qty, setQty] = useState(1);

  const onAdd = (product, quantity) => {
    const checkProductInCart = cartItems.find((item) => item._id === product._id);
  
    setTotalPrice((prevTotalPrice) => prevTotalPrice + product.price * quantity);
    setTotalQuantities((prevTotalQuantities) => prevTotalQuantities + quantity);
    
    if(checkProductInCart) {
      const updatedCartItems = cartItems.map((cartProduct) => {
        if(cartProduct._id === product._id) return {
          ...cartProduct,
          quantity: cartProduct.quantity + quantity
        }
      })

      setCartItems(updatedCartItems);
    } else {
      product.quantity = quantity;
      
      setCartItems([...cartItems, { ...product }]);
    }

    toast.success(`${qty} ${product.name} added to the cart.`);
  } 

  // Some more codes...

  return (
    <Context.Provider
      value={{
        //all global state exports... 
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </Context.Provider>
  )
}

export const useStateContext = () => useContext(Context);
          return {
            ...cartProduct,
            quantity: cartProduct.quantity + quantity,
          }
      })

      setCartItems(updatedCartItems)
    } else {
      product.quantity = quantity

      setCartItems([...cartItems, {...product}])
    }

    toast.success(`${qty} ${product.name} added to the cart.`)
  }

  // Some more codes...

  return (
    <Context.Provider
      value={
        {
          //all global state exports...
        }
      }>
      {children}
    </Context.Provider>
  )
}

export const useStateContext = () => useContext(Context)
```

Comment: a minimally reproducible example is needed

Comment: Could you please share the full code in the file where `<button type="button" className={styles.add_to_cart} onClick={() =>onAdd(product,qty)} >Add to Cart</button>` is located

Comment: @TachibanaShin I've edit my post. Hope it gives better clarity.

Comment: @ScottMitchell Yeah, It's located in ProductDetail page. But I suppose the error is from Cart.tsx

Comment: I think you can fix the error by replacing this code: `const updatedCartItems = cartItems.map((cartProduct) => {
        if(cartProduct._id === product._id) return {
          ...cartProduct,
          quantity: cartProduct.quantity + quantity
        }
      })` with `const updatedCartItems = cartItems.map((cartProduct) => {
        if(cartProduct._id === product._id) return {
          ...cartProduct,
          quantity: cartProduct.quantity + quantity
        }
return cardProduct
      })`

Comment: @TachibanaShin Hey it worked! Thanks brother. Btw, can u explain how it works internally?

Comment: basically we need to return what is unmodified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem stems from the way you generate `updatedCartItems`:

```
const updatedCartItems = cartItems.map((cartProduct) => {
  if (cartProduct._id === product._id) {
    return {
      ...cartProduct,
      quantity: cartProduct.quantity + quantity
    };
  }
});
```

[`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) creates an array element for every element in the original array. For every case where the if condition is not matched, you implicitly return `undefined`. This new array with some valid items and some undefined ones is then set into your state.

To exemplify, the code you have right now is functionally equivalent to the following:

```
const updatedCartItems = cartItems.map((cartProduct) => {
  if (cartProduct._id === product._id) {
    return {
      ...cartProduct,
      quantity: cartProduct.quantity + quantity
    };
  } else {
    return undefined;
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes, Though I thought that since we are checking checkProductInCart at top level function it should definitely hit the if condition block. Good explanation btw :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're pushing single object into cartItems. Therefore object can't contain length properties. Therefor you should Like below sample code:

```
cartItems.map((cartProduct)=>{
       if(cartProduct._id===product._id){
         let newQantity=cartProduct.quantity + quantity;
         setCartProduct([
          ...cartItems,
          {
           ...cartProduct,
           quantity:newQuantity
          }
         ])
       }
    })
```